# Mapbox custom user location annotation image and position

Tags: ios, mapbox

I want to be able to display a custom image for the user location on a Mapbox map in iOS, *and* be able to set the current user location from an internal source, rather than using the internal GPS source.

The built-in user location facility appears to only be able to source location from the Mapbox internal location engine. I have added a custom annotation to the map, and I can update its position when I get a new location fix, but the motion is jerky (I can pan the map with a camera animation, but not the annotation.)

Is there any way in the iOS Mapbox SDK to animate changing the location of an annotation?

Comment: Can you explain your needs a bit more? If you want to feed different location data for the user location than the GPS would supply then presumably you don’t want to actually show the real (lat, long) of the phone’s actual position? If that’s the case why don’t you just hide the default user location marker and use your own annotation for your own location data?

Comment: The location is coming from an external GPS receiver. So it is the device's position, just not obtained from the internal GPS (not all iDevices have internal GPS in any case.) As explained above, I am adding my own annotation, but there appears to be no built-in way of smoothly animating changes in its location, whereas the `MGLUserLocationAnnotation` animates changes.

Comment: The Mapbox SDK for Android has a plugin for the current location, and it has a method `forceLocationUpdate()` which allows injection of an externally derived location. That works well, I'm trying to replicate the same functionality on iOS.

Comment: It looks like there is a [PR in the works](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/12013) that may help with your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I came up with. In the `MGLMapViewDelegate` I use the `didFinishRenderingFrame()` callback to update the location, interpolating between the two most recent locations.
`posAnnotation` is the `MGLPointAnnotation` associated with `flightMarker` which is an `MGLAnnotationView` extended to add a `UIImageView` and hold the locations.

```
        override fun didFinishRenderingFrame(mapView: MGLMapView, fullyRendered: Boolean) {
            val frac = min((CFDate.getCurrentAbsoluteTime() - lastUpdateTimestamp) / lastUpdateInterval, 1.0)
            if(flightMarker.location.valid)
                posAnnotation.coordinate = flightMarker.interpolatedLocation(frac)
        }

        override fun viewForAnnotation(mapView: MGLMapView, annotation: MGLAnnotation): MGLAnnotationView? {
            return if (annotation == posAnnotation) flightMarker else null
        }
```

Comment: I used the same approach a few years later on MapBox v11. This is far from ideal, but working as expected. Thanks!